# How to disable automatic cropping that's done after distortion correction in DxO Optics Pro 9 or 10?

Tags: cropping, distortion, rotation, dxo-optics

DxO uses so-called "modules" that apparently contain many lens parameters and they are implicitly used for correcting geometric distortion, and some other issues in pictures automatically. But the resulting image is rectangular (it doesn't contain any undefined areas near the sides), that means it was also automatically cropped after the distortion correction. Is there a way to get the cropped parts back? (for example, if I want to rotate the photo, it would also require me to crop some parts, but cropping is better to do once, because otherwise I can lose too much picture area)

I know that internally DxO can probably keep track of undefined area and do the cropping only once, but if I want to use DxO just for batch-processing pictures with lens correction and then do all other work somewhere else, this option is a must have.

I tried to illustrate:

[image: a picture]

black contour: boundaries of an image after distortion correction

red contour: what I can get

green contour: what I want (no picture area is thrown away)

#### Update — disclaimer:

Since the time I asked this question I've given up photography for various reasons :( but if someone knows the answer, maybe it'll still help someone who has (or wants to have) similar workflow.

Comment: It seems that I have a similar problem (with understanding something crucial) here: http://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/69808/why-does-lens-distortion-correction-also-crop

Comment: Is there any "scale" value like in ACR 6.7? ACR 6.7 applies crop as well but it may be cancelled out with "scale" being less than 1.